# How would this jump instruction be encoded in Intel64?

Tags: assembly, encoding, x86-64

I have a question about encoding as I am just starting out with Intel64 disassembly. How would the instruction `jmp *%rsp` be encoded? Since it is using the `*`(pointer), I am a bit confused. Does this make the encoding special? I can't seem to find anything on that in the manual?

So far, I'm guessing `jmp *%rsp` should be encoded as: `ff c0` considering the register being used, etc.  Would `ff c0` be correct, or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just feed it to an assembler? It's `ff e4` by the way. `ff c0` is `inc %eax`.

The `*` means indirect jump in at&t syntax. It's necessary to differentiate between `jmp foo` and `jmp *foo`, where the former is a simple relative jump but the latter is an indirect jump through a pointer. The `*` is optional in this case because it is not ambiguous (although it will trigger a warning). The counterpart would be `jmp *(%rsp)` and that differs by the parentheses.

The intel instruction set reference entry for this instruction is `ff /4 jmp r/m64`.
Looking up the `/4` in the modr/m encoding table 2.2, we see the value for `esp` (which maps to `rsp` in 64 bit mode) is indeed `e4`.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to use an online assembler: https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly

```
ff e4  jmp rsp
```